# Ignore 2nd level child using automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, automapper-4

```
public class Source
{
   public ChildSource ChildSource { get; set; }
   //some other properties 
}

public class ChildSource
{
   public List<GrandChildSource> GrandChildSources { get; set; }
   //some other properties
}

public class GrandChildSource
{
   Public ChildSource ChildSource { get; set; }
   //some other properties
}

And Dto classes:

public class SourceDto
{
   public ChildSourceDto ChildSource { get; set; }
   //some other properties
}

public class ChildSourceDto
{
   public List<GrandChildSourceDto> GrandChildSources { get; set; }
   //some other properties
}

public class GrandChildSourceDto
{
   Public ChildSourceDto ChildSource { get; set; }
   //some other properties
}
```

I would like to map source/childsource classes to dto classes and ignore GrandChildSources property.

I have tried using UseDestinationValue and Ignore but it seems to be not working.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, SourceDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildSource, opt => { opt.UseDestinationValue(); opt.Ignore(); })
                .AfterMap((source, destination) => Mapper.Map(source.ChildSource, destination.ChildSource));

Mapper.CreateMap<ChildSource, ChildSourceDto>()
                .ForMember(d => d.GrandChildSources, opt => { opt.UseDestinationValue(); opt.Ignore(); });
```

Getting error "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping for GrandChildSource"

PS: LazyLoadingEnabled is set to True. I decided to ignore GrandChildSources property after getting Stack overflow exception as it has got circular reference .

Comment: Are you doing one-way or two-way mapping?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think it is one-way mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this should be fairly simple with straightforward mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, SourceDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ChildSource, ChildSourceDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.GrandChildSources, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Alternately you could ignore the `ChildSource` property on GrandChildSourceDto to avoid your circular reference problem.

If there's something more complex than this, please clarify what the problem is.